# How to use ad7490 with android things?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, iot, gpio, spi, android-things

How to use ad7490 ADC in Android Things?

I have a sensor 16x16 Sensor Matrix. For this sensor matrix i want to read data of the each cell and position. I want to implement ad7490 ADC with the help of SPI and GPIO Pins connection.

My requirement is, how to read ad7490 A2D value on SPI pin.

Note : I had also implemented this on arduino uno using ic 7495 shift register and 74hc4067 mux. By these i am able to generate 16x16 matrix and read Analog data of each position. Now i want to implement same thing in android things with ad7490

Comment: Note : I had also implemented this on arduino uno using ic 7495 shift register and 74hc4067 mux. By these i am able to generate 16x16 matrix and read Analog data of each position. Now i want to implement same thing in android things with ad7490

Comment: the short answer is: There is no simple way for you to use that sensor on AndroidThings